# Criminal Records Check for non-EU citizen wanting to be a teaching assistant

Tags: criminal-records

Apologies if this is in the wrong place.

My wife ( Argentinian) is now living with me in the UK having obtained her UK Residence Card as a Family Member (EU residence) We came under the Surinder Singh provisions last December.

She is a qualified teacher in Argentina and we know that she needs to undertake QTS training here. However, to get herself into the system, she is looking at Teaching Assistant posts.
A huge barrier seems to be the need for a criminal records check from Argentina. Logistically that is extremely difficult for her. Does anyone know the precise rules that the Department of Education have given to employment agencies regarding this matter?

Comment: Perhaps you'll find some guidance on this UK Dept of Education page: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/criminal-records-checks-for-overseas-applicants

Comment: Thanks David. I'm aware of the site and it was what was given to us by an employment agency. However, it does not specify which jobs require a check. For example, applications for a Tier 2 ( General) visa would require said check, but my wife is not classed as a teacher here, just an assistant.                                                                                                              She didn't need a check for her current job as a care worker nor for her voluntary work with her church nursery class. The enhanced DBS check was sufficient plus her HO UK Residence card.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't helpful. About halfway down the page is this: *If you have any comments about the information contained in the main documents, or spot any errors, please contact ICIT@homeoffice.gsi.gov.uk* Perhaps you should ask DoE directly.

Comment: I'm thankful for your time David and your suggestions. Yes, contacting the DoE is probably the best option. I was just hoping someone may just have come across the same problem. Thanks again.Kevin